# Issue while printing a raster image on POS Thermal Printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, raster, thermal-printer, pos

Actually i'm trying to print a raster image on a Thermal Printer

(actually tryed two different types of printer and having same issue)

The printing image is making a white line every group of byte's that i'm sending.

As you can see on the screen below i was trying to print the following picture:

[image]

But this is the result when i've printed it and same issue with any other image:

[image]

Here is the code where i was trying to print an inique black line

```
For i = 1 To 60 * 1

    appIMG &= Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255)

    appIMG &= Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255)

    appIMG &= Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255)

    appIMG &= Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255)
Next
```

And with the following code this is the result

[image]

64 are width byte and 120 bit in height so the max image size is 512px x 120px for row

```
NewSer.WriteLine (Chr(29) & Chr(118) & Chr(48) & Chr(48) & Chr(64) & Chr(0) & Chr(120) & Chr(0) & appIMG)

NewSer.WriteLine (Chr(29) & Chr(118) & Chr(48) & Chr(48) & Chr(64) & Chr(0) & Chr(120) & Chr(0) & appIMG)

NewSer.WriteLine (Chr(29) & Chr(118) & Chr(48) & Chr(48) & Chr(64) & Chr(0) & Chr(120) & Chr(0) & appIMG)

NewSer.WriteLine (Chr(29) & Chr(118) & Chr(48) & Chr(48) & Chr(64) & Chr(0) & Chr(120) & Chr(0) & appIMG)
```

Comment: Is `NewSer` a [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) instance?  If it is, what is value of the [SerialPort.Encoding Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Also, why not just write out a byte array instead of as string?

Comment: @TnTinMn yes NewSer is a SerialPort istance and i'm writing it as a String cause it's more clear to see what i'm doing, while the Encoding Propert is ASCII

Comment: How did you configure the `NewSer` instance regarding start bits, stop bits and parity?